# Cant run custom CLI

Tags: node.js

I made a CLI for my project. Its in the bin folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// myproj/bin/cli.js
console.log('hello');
```

I linked the bin by using `npm link`. But when I run

```
$ cli
```

I get an error `cli not found`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the bin directory in your PATH?

Comment: I think `npm link` is supposed to take care of this for you?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, npm linking is a two step process as it says in the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) page, so you are missing the second step. Linking is basically a way for you to introduce a dependency in another module you are working on.

Secondly, If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve (*run the module that you are developing locally as a global module*), you can just use `npm install -g` command, from inside the project folder that you are developing.

This will install, your global module on your machine and will allow you to run it.